# Exclude taxonomy Query if post_type

Tags: taxonomy, query, pre-get-posts

How can I define in `pre_get_posts` hook on custom post type to not execute the query on a taxonomy.

I have the following

```
if (!empty($newsType) && $newsType == 'press') {
    //if $newsType exclude the taxonomy query and get just the post_type
    $taxQuery = [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'news_type',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ]
    ];

    $this->query->set('post_type', ['press']);
    $this->query->set( 'tax_query', $taxQuery );

} else {
    $this->query->set('post_type', ['news', 'press']);
}
```

`$newsType` is the `$_GET`variable from request

If I do the following
`unset($this->query->query_vars['news_type']);` the query will break with

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "not execute the query on a taxonomy". Also, what is `$newsType`?

Comment: I made a comment to the post, between I fixed the problem like passing another name as GET variable and set the tax_query on this condition